# NextJS On-demand entries Returns 404

Tags: next.js, vercel, webpack-hmr

I'm currently experiencing an issue with on-demand entries where when it requests a page to be compiled on the fly, it returns a 404 from the dev-server.

Below is the typical pages directory structure. When inspecting dev_tools console, there is a fetch call to the dev server to compile the page, in this case article.tsx (/article/article-slug), the fetch request returns a 404.

```
.
+-- pages
|   +-- latest-news
|       +-- index.tsx
|   +-- article
|       +-- [slug].tsx
```

Environment Details:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- Node: v15.8.0
- NPM: 6.14.11
- NextJS: 10.0.5

Comment: Is the page you're requesting statically generated (`getStaticProps`) or server-side rendered (`getServerSideProps`)? Care to share its code?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `pages/article/[article-slug].tsx` page if you want NextJS to recognize the slug.

Follow the [NextJS tutorial](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) for more details

Comment: My mistake, I used a bad example here. While your response is correct and that is what is applied in the other pages in the project, there is another page in the same format pages/latest-news/index.tsx -> /latest-news that is also returning a 404 like the article page.

Comment: One thing I have noted while looking into the issue is that if you can the "revalidate" property in the getStaticProps method, the 404 issue goes away even on pages where the property was not changed.

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66923017/4286130